# Is there free parking on Bodø, Norway?

Tags: automobiles, norway

Is there any free parking in Bodø City and around?
I need to go to the city and most likely wait in or around town for several days for stuff to arrive. I wonder if there is free (short-term) parking in the city and if there is good parking, maybe somewhere with nature, around Bodo, where I can wait and not disturb anyone for several days.
I am driving a Micro Camper that allows me to live in it without needing special big-size parking lots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Daytime 08-18, Mon-Sat, there is no free parking in the city center marked by the blue and green zones on [this map](https://kommunekart.com/klient/bod%C3%B8?urlid=fa9665af-f16d-465b-b7df-5f369f8db0dc). Evenings, nights and Sundays are free.

Outside the city, there are usually no parking restrictions. As long as you don't disturb anyone (keeping a distance from populated buildings is always a good idea) and don't need any facilities like water or a toilet, there should be no problem to park a micro camper at most locations.

[image]

Comment: There's also a small no-free-parking area by what appears to be a shopping mall southeast of the city center.